# SBT. Как правильно организовать Classpath dependencies между двумя проектами?

Tags: scala, sbt

Есть 2 проекта `P1` и `P2`, лежащие на одном уровне:

IdeaProjects\
     |—P1\
     |—P2\

В первом проекте есть простой класс:

```
class Common {
    def sayHi: Unit = println("Hi!")
}
```

Согласно [документации](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies), я пытаюсь использовать этот класс во втором проекте. Для этого пытаюсь организовать между ними `Classpath dependencies`.
`build.sbt` второго проекта:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
)

lazy val P1 = (project in file("P1")).settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "P1"
)

lazy val P2 = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(P1).settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "P2"
)
```

Однако при попытке создать класс `Common` во втором проекте, получаю ошибку:

> Cannot resolve symbol Common

---

Также пробовал прописать `P1` так:

```
lazy val P1 = (project in file("../P1")).settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "P1"
)
```

В этом случае получаю :

> [error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Directory C:\Users\08407540\IdeaProjects\P1 is not contained in build root C:\Users\08407540\IdeaProjects\P2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не верно понял документацию. `build.sbt` с описанием проектов должен быть не во втором проекте а вне их. Что-то вроде:
IdeaProjects\
 |—P3\
  |—P1\
  |—P2\
  |—build.sbt

Comment: Да, верно. Один внешний проект P3, который лежит в папке IdeaProjects, внутри которого лежат build.sbt и две папки-проекта P1 и P2. Потом, зайдя в sbt, можешь написать комманду `projects` и увидеть список видимых ему проектов.